# How to prevent NGINX proxy from forwarding to itself

Tags: nginx

How can I prevent the NGINX proxy from forwarding to itself?

I run a http server (port 80) and a forwarding proxy (8080) with cache on the same host. Thus it is a valid scenario that the proxy forwards to port 80 on the same host.

When somebody accidentally sends a request to port 8080 (instead of 80), the proxy enters a perpetual loop.

- The proxy declares a cache miss and passes the request (to itself).
- The proxy receives the forwarded request. I am using proxy_cache_lock, so the proxy waits for 5 seconds for the original request to complete.
- After 5 seconds it handles the forwarded request anyway, and forwards it again.
- The second forwarded request again is held for 5 seconds, then proceeds the same way.

The end result is I get a 499 error ever 5 seconds.

Within the `location` block that contains the `proxy_pass directive`, I would like to check if the requested host/port is the same as the proxy host/port, and if so return an error.

How could I do that?

Config (partial):

```
# caching forward proxy
server {

    listen 8089;
    server_name _;

    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 ipv6=off;

    proxy_cache caching-forward-proxy;
    proxy_cache_revalidate on;
    proxy_cache_lock on;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;    

    # location for forward proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting `if ($http_host = 'server_name_with_port') { return 404; }` to `location` block before `proxy_pass`?

Comment: @m1ch4ls: Thanks, that works. However, it requires the hostname and port, and any aliases (including the IP address), to be hard-coded in the config file. I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution.